# iOS Custom UITableViewCell Looks not all the same

Tags: ios, uitableview

I use UIView's extension to custome a UITableViewCell display:

```
import UIKit

private var materialKey = false
private var _cornerRadius = 3.0
private var _borderWidth = 0.0

extension UIView{

@IBInspectable var borderWidth:Double{
    get{
        return _borderWidth
    }

    set{
        _borderWidth = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius:Double{
    get{
        return _cornerRadius
    }

    set{
        _cornerRadius = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable var materialDesign:Bool{
    get{
        return materialKey
    }

    set{
        materialKey = newValue
        if materialKey{
            self.layer.masksToBounds = false
            self.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(_cornerRadius)
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
            self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 157/255, green: 157/255, blue: 157/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        }else{
            layer.cornerRadius = 0
            layer.shadowOpacity = 0
            layer.shadowRadius = 0
            layer.shadowColor = nil
        }
    }
}
```

But,When I run App(Whether it is real device or simulator)，it‘s look like  that:

[image]

The first Cell and the other do not look the same :(
Can anyone tell me why??? thank you!

Comment: Pay attention first cell‘s border

Comment: You done code work and even no one knows what actually you wanted to implement. So how could we know about this. Improve your question quality. Thanks

Comment: May be you need to call your tableview with on different thread instead of main. As because the table is not able to apply effect the time table load. If you scroll and come back to this cell. It would have the changes but not on first time load

Comment: @cole Thats not true.

Comment: I saw images on cell. I have seen when you have images and more content on cell. It skips some content on first few cells. As the way to debug is scroll and come back to those unchanged cell and this time it will have the changes. Its a good to way to find the issue

Comment: Ok,I want custome UITableViewCell in iOS,eg:shadow at cell border.the code make a extension from UIView,and I open My custome cell view attributes's materialKey to true to open custom effect.

Comment: apply shadow layer in override func layoutsubviews(), or reload table view in viewdidappear once.